# Parsing node-rest-client response when the response is in HTML format

Tags: node.js, node-rest-client

I have an endpoint I'm testing using Node.js node-rest-client

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    client.post(`${url}/auth/auth`, authArgs, function (authData) {
      if (debug) {
        console.log("Received authData:");
        console.log(authData);
        console.log();
```

if authData fails the response is in HTML, and when trying to print it I receive the following

```
Received authData:
<Buffer 49 6e 74 65 67 72 69 74 79 45 72 72 6f 72 20 61 74 20 2f 61 75 74 68 65 6e 74 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 61 75 74 68 65 6e 74 69 63 61 74 65 0a 6e 75 6c ... >
```

How can I have this HTML to be parsed properly so it can show the error message properly instead of a buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output error is [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), its a stream of binary, and to convert it to string you can just do:

```
...
console.log(authData.toString('utf8'));
...
```